# do while loop using an if statement to print odd numbers

Tags: c#, loops, if-statement, while-loop, do-while

At the moment I am learning loops. I am trying to create a console application which uses a do while loop to print all odd integers between 20 and 0.

Why when I uncomment `if` statement below my code does not print anything and never finishes?

```
using System;

class Program
{
  static void Main(string[] args)
  {
     int i = 20;
     do 
     {
        // if (i%2 !=0)
        {
           Console.WriteLine(
              "When counting down from 20 the odd values are: {0}", i--);
        }
      } while (i >=0);
   }
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with the `if` that you have now (other than the fact that it is commented)?

Comment: @David: The fact that `i--` is inside, so it gets stuck as soon as it reaches an even value.

Answer (score 3):

I think the main issue you're having is that the decrement (`i--`) only occurs inside the if block. That means when the condition fails, you will enter an infite loop. You can move the decrement outside the if block to fix that. Try this:

```
Console.Write("When counting down from 20 the odd values are: ");
do 
{
    if (i % 2 != 0)
    {
        Console.Write(" {0}", i);
    }

    i--;
} while (i >= 0);
```

I also moved the first `Console.Write` outside the loop to reduce redundancy in the output. This will produce:

> When counting down from 20 the odd values are: 19 17 15 13 11 9 7 5 3 1

Comment: +1. Nice explanation and safest place to do decrement. Inlining `--`/`++` can be done later when one understands basic operations. Also there is generally nothing to be gained by combining decrement and other operation except making code looking like written by "seasoned C programmer" :)

Answer (score 1):

A for loop may be easier to follow:

```
Console.WriteLine("When counting down from 20 the odd values are: ");
for( int i = 20; i >= 0; i--)
{
    if (i%2 !=0)
    {
       Console.Write(" " + i);
    } 
}
```

Comment: +0: while correct it not going to help OP as it shows different loop.

Comment: The OP is learning loops. Showing another, and in this case better, form of loop is certainly helpful.

Comment: Note that  this form of loop has the advantage of checking the initial value ... if the initial and final values were parameterized, this won't fail if the initial value is < the final value, whereas the do loop will.

Comment: @JimBalter: Both `while` and `for` loops are a required art of a programmers toolkit. In fact the while loop is more general and arguably simpler, and appropriately taught first. Confusing the OP with another loop of more restricted use is not at all useful. If, however, the OP were a more seasoned developer, then suggesting a more learned technique would be appropriate.

Comment: Aside from being pointlessly argumentative, that's ridiculous on several counts, not least of which is that the OP used a `do ... while` loop, not `while` loop. This answer deserves a +1 which I gave, not this absurd BS about it not being helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I know this is really old and the initial question was for a DO not a FOR, but I wanted to add what I did to accomplish this outcome.  When I Googled the question initially, this is what was returned first despite my query being for a FOR loop.  Hopefully someone down the road will find this helpful.

The below will print the odd number index of an array - in this case, Console App args.

```
using System;
namespace OddCounterTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < args.Length; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(i);
                i++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Output with 6 arguments will be:
    1
    3
    5

Moving i++ to the first step in the for loop will get you the even numbers.

```
using System;
namespace EvenCounterTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < args.Length; i++)
            {
                i++;
                Console.WriteLine(i);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Output will be:
    2
    3
    4

This is setup so you can get the also actual values of the args too rather than simply the count and print of the args index.  Just create a string and set the string to args[i]:

```
string s = args[i];
Console.WriteLine(s);
```

If you need to count and exclude "0" in the event your are printing numbers like the question initially asks, then setup your for loop like so:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= args.Length; i++);
```

Notice how "i" is initially set to 1 in this example and i is less than or equal to the array length rather than simply less than.  Be mindful of your less than and less than/equal to's or you will get OutOfRangeExceptions.

Answer (score -1):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace Do_while_Test
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int i = 20;
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("A do while loop printing odd values from 20 - 0 ");
         do 
         {
            if (i-- %2 !=0)
            {
             Console.WriteLine("When counting down from 20 the odd values are: {0}", i--);
            }

         } while (i >=0);
         Console.ReadLine();  
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: If you're going to decrement twice, you don't even need the condition.  (And in fact, this will print the even values)

Comment: @BenVoigt you are smart~~~ haha, 'And in fact, this will print the even values' yep, I knew I will be wrong with this, kkk, will be careful next time

Comment: -1: Suggesting `++`/`--` as part of `if` statement for person just learning loops is not the best idea. Plus as Ben Voigt pointed out you end up with completely wrong code - 2 decrements, and it'll never print odd numbers.

Comment: "I knew I will be wrong with this" -- then why did you post it? Answers to questions should not be even buggier than the code in the question.

Comment: wait a minute, if (i-- %2 !=0) that should print odd number, right? is odd numbers are 19, 17, 15...?

Comment: It will print the odd numbers, but once it prints the first one (19) it will skip the even numbers without testing them ... thus the comment that you don't even need the condition.

Comment: How come it will skip the even numbers without testing them? i starts from 20, 20 % 2 = 0 which fails the condition, then it goes to 19, 19 % 2 = 1, pass the condition, print. Then 18, 18 % 2 = 0, fail the condition, and it will go on checking 17, 16, 15... Or were you talking about doing i-- twice?